# Any standard C#.NET way to utilize WMI IPHelper?

Tags: c#, dll, iphelper

Does anyone know if there is an existing C#.NET namespace that contains the equivalent of the WMI IPHelper functions?  Specifically I need to call CreateIpForwardEntry and DeleteIpForwardEntry.  Is the only way via P/Invoke?  (NOTE:  this isn't a request for third-party libraries, but for standard .NET libraries)

Comment: This not a request "to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource".  I think that is pretty clear.  I want to know how to call CreateIpForwardEntry from .NET.  Why is this off-topic for SO?

Comment: I agree that this is _not_ off topic.

Comment: Thanks for the support Jason.  The question was put on hold when I first posted it.  After rewording to make it clear that I wasn't looking for third-party library rcommendations, the revised question was voted to be reopened.  Once successfully reopened I don't think SO should allow a question to be put on hold a second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I decided not to bother with trying to P/Invoke WMI IPHelper functions.  It was much easier to just kick-off a process opening cmd.exe and writing the console commands to add and remove route.  The code below illustrates how this can be done.

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

proc.Start();
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(delete
    ? "route delete " + ServiceIpAddress + " mask " + GatewayMask + " " + GatewayIpAddress + " -p" : "route add " + ServiceIpAddress + " mask " + GatewayMask + " " +  GatewayIpAddress + " -p");
roc.Close();
```